# Flutter:Dart unzip & save response from http

Tags: flutter, dart

i need help for this:
Using Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 & Dart 2.7.0
i receive a zip response.bodyBytes from an http.get
how can i zipdecode and save directly to disk ?

This an extract of my code to show what i'm searching:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
...
  var basicAuth = 'my auth';
  Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
  headers.putIfAbsent('authorization', () => basicAuth);
  headers.putIfAbsent('Content-Type', () => 'application/json');

  var url = 'http://myhost';

  http.Response response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: headers,
  );

  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = dir.path + '/';
  String fn = 'filename.xxx';
  new File(path + fn).writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes); // This cmd store zip file to disk
  // In my case i've a zip file with only one file inside, below a code to unzip all files inside zip
  // Extract the contents of the Zip archive to disk.
  for (ArchiveFile file in archive) {
    String filename = file.name;
    if (file.isFile) {
      List<int> data = file.content;
      File('out/' + filename)
        ..createSync(recursive: true)
        ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
    } else {
      Directory('out/' + filename)
        ..create(recursive: true);
    }
  }
  // Instead i'd like to unzip the only one file there's inside
```

Comment: I solved using _unzip function found here: https://github.com/gracyaneoliveira/apps-flutter/blob/7840998961d7fbc3269df1da313f36aa94412bba/fireapp/lib/service/package_service.dart

This function unzip all files in one zip archive

Answer (score 1):

IF your data is in gzip format you can try

```dart
GZipCodec().decode(response.bodyBytes);
```

Comment: i know how to decode:
final archive = new ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(response.bodyBytes);
i don't know how to save it to disk

Comment: You know how to decode. What you need to know is how to describe the problem you are having so others can help you. Also, you're welcome.

Comment: @MauroMiotello Here's a guide on writing files with Dart IO:  https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartio  . It would be helpful to see the code you've tried so far.